# Can Node's Date.now() precision be reduced or tuned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

Can Node's Date.now() precision be reduced or tuned -- to a specific value, or to some predetermined value, like round to the nearest 10ms? For example, something similar to [Firefox's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Reduced_time_precision) `privacy.reduceTimerPrecision`, `privacy.resistFingerprinting`, `privacy.resistFingerprinting.reduceTimerPrecision.microseconds`?

Comment: Since you have full control over your Node code, couldn't you reduce/tune it by simply implementing your own rounding logic to apply to the returned value? In the case of Firefox, it sounds like a user-configurable, browser-side preference which web developers need to potentially anticipate, but on the server side, you've got full control over rounding to whatever precision you want.

Comment: Are you trying to *increase* precision? Similar to as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117537/how-to-get-microsecond-timings-in-javascript-since-spectre-and-meltdown)?

Comment: No @MattJohnson-Pint, more the reverse, but that's an interesting one as well.

Comment: Well then, Alan's answer is spot on.  Even `privacy.reduceTimerPrecision` isn't a good route, because that is *on* by default, to mitigate Spectre/Meltdown attacks.  Turning it off increases precision.  Keeping it on reduces precision in Firefox only, but by an indeterminate amount (varying by version of Firefox, per the docs you linked).  Thus, you're better off writing the logic yourself.  If you need to do this globally for some reason, you could "monkey-patch" the `Date` object prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the Date methods to do this

e.g.

```
const nowToNearestMinute = new Date().setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
```